# Elastic Search - grouping on a field and get most matched single record

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am new in Elastic Search. I would like to get category wise most matched(Score wise) single record. Lets take a example.

1. My Index detail

   PUT  commentdetail
   {
   "mappings": {
   "properties": {
   "category" : {
   "type": "text"
   },
   "comment" : {
   "type": "text"
   }

   ```
    }
   ```

   }
   }
2. Sample Data

   ```
    category    Comment
   ```

---

```
    fruit       I like apple
    fruit       I like apple and banana
    fruit       I like banana and apple
    fruit       I like banana but not apple
    fruit       I like apple but not banana
    fruit       I like banana
    vegetable   I like potato
    vegetable   I like potato and tomato
    vegetable   I like tomato and potato
    vegetable   I like tomato but not potato
    vegetable   I like potato but not tomato
    vegetable   I like tomato
```

3. Expected Result
   If I search "i like" on comment field then expected output is

   GET commentdetail/_search
   {
   "query": {
   "match_phrase": {
   "comment": "I like"
   }
   }
   }

### Result:

```
    category    Comment
    -----------------------
    Fruit       I like apple
    Vegetable   I like potato
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your required result by using a combination of terms and top hits aggregation.

But in order to use aggregation you need to update your index mapping, to have `keyword` type field for `category`

**You can either update your index mapping, by following the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex) or create a new index, with the below index mapping**.

---

Adding a working example:

**Index Mapping:**

```
PUT <index-name>
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "category": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "comment": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST <index-name>/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "comment": "I like"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "category": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "category.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_comments_based_on_category": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "_score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
        "category": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "fruit",
                    "doc_count": 6,
                    "top_comments_based_on_category": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 6,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.09186296,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "73716847",
                                    "_id": "5",
                                    "_score": 0.09186296,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "comment": "I like apple",
                                        "category": "fruit"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "vegetable",
                    "doc_count": 6,
                    "top_comments_based_on_category": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 6,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.09186296,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "73716847",
                                    "_id": "3",
                                    "_score": 0.09186296,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "comment": "I like potato",
                                        "category": "vegetable"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ankur patel did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Yes, I got it.....Thank you Bhavya for your help